# Using the value from a login view control

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get the name (value) from a login view status contraol when a user in logged into my asp.net website. I want to put this value or login name into a textbox when the page loads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Marlon Gowdie

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user has been authenticated then you can get the current user from the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property of the current [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx).  More than likely this is what the [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control is using internally to get the current user information.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple example  how to get the login name using login status control...

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <script runat="server">


  protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    string name = Login1.UserName;

  }

  </script>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
   <title>Untitled Page</title>
  </head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">

 <div>
  <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn">
 </asp:Login>

  </div>

</form>

</body>
```